# Perl + Curses: Expecting a UTF-8 encoded multibyte character from getchar(), but not getting any

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, locale, ncurses

I am trying out Bryan Henderson's Perl interface to the ncurses library: [Curses](https://metacpan.org/release/Curses)

For a simple exercise, I try to obtain single characters typed on-screen. This is directly based off the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/init.html#ABOUTINIT), with adaptations.

When I call the Perl library's `getchar()`, I expect to receive a character, possibly multibyte (It's a bit more complicated as explained in [this part of the library manpage](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses#Wide-Character-Aware-Functions) because one has to handle the special cases of function keys and no input, but that's just the usual curlicues).

It's the subroutine `read1ch()` in the code below.

This works well for ASCII characters, but doesn't work for characters above 0x7F. For example, when hitting `è` (Unicode 0x00E8, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description): 0xC3, 0xA8), I actually obtain code 0xE8 instead of something UTF-8 encoded. Printing it out to the terminal for which `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` is not working and anyway I was expecting 0xC3A8.

What do I need to change to make it work, i.e. get the `è` either as a proper character or a Perl string?

The C code snipped for `getchar()` is [here](https://metacpan.org/source/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.36/CursesFunWide.c) btw. Maybe it just didn't get compiled with `C_GET_WCH` set? How to find out?

## Addenda

### Addendum 1

Tried with setting the [binmode](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) using

```perl
binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

which should fix any encoding issues because the terminal expects and sends UTF-8, but that didn't help.

Also tried setting the stream encoding with [use open](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) (not quite sure about the difference between this and the approach above), but that didn't help either

```perl
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
```

### Addendum 2

The manpage for the [Perl Curses shim](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses#Wide-Character-Aware-Functions) says:

> If `wget_wch()` is not available (i.e. The Curses library does not
>   understand wide characters), this calls `wgetch()` [get a 1-byte char
>   from a curses window], but returns the
>   values described above nonetheless. This can be a problem because with a
>   multibyte character encoding like UTF-8, you will receive two 
>   one-character strings for a two-byte-character (e.g. "Ã" and "¤" for
>   "ä").

This may be the case here, but `wget_wch()` does exist on this system.

### Addendum 3

Tried to see what the C code does and added an `fprintf` directly into the multibyte handling code of `curses/Curses-1.36/CursesFunWide.c`, recompiled, didn't manage to override the system `Curses.so` with my own via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (why not? why is everything only working half of the time?), so replaced the system library directly in place (take THAT!).

```
#ifdef C_GET_WCH
    wint_t wch;
    int ret = wget_wch(win, &wch);
    if (ret == OK) {
        ST(0) = sv_newmortal();
        fprintf(stderr,"Obtained win_t 0x%04lx\n", wch);
        c_wchar2sv(ST(0), wch);
        XSRETURN(1);
    } else if (ret == KEY_CODE_YES) {
        XST_mUNDEF(0);
        ST(1) = sv_newmortal();
        sv_setiv(ST(1), (IV)wch);
        XSRETURN(2);
    } else {
        XSRETURN_UNDEF;
    }
#else
```

That's just a fat NOPE, when pressing `ü` one sees:

```
Obtained win_t 0x00fc
```

So the *correct code is run*, but the data is *ISO-8859-1*, not UTF-8. So it's `wget_wch` which behaves badly. So it's a curses config problem. Huh.

### Addendum 4

It struck me that maybe `ncurses` was assuming default locale, i.e. `C`. To make it `ncurses` work with wide characters, one has to "initialize the locale", which probably means moving state from "unset" (and thus making `ncurses` fall back to `C`) to "set to what the system indicates" (which should be what is in the `LANG` environment variable). The man page for `ncurses` says:

> The library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized.
>   That is normally done with setlocale:
>
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
>
> If  the locale is not initialized, the library assumes that characters
>   are printable as in ISO-8859-1, to work with certain legacy programs.
>   You should initialize the locale and not rely on specific details of the
>   library when the locale has not been setup.

This didn't work either, but I feel that the solution is down that road.

### Addendum 5

The `win_t` (apparently the same as `wchar_t`) conversion code from [`CursesWide.c`](https://metacpan.org/source/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.36/CursesWide.c), converts the `wint_t` (here seen as `wchar_t`) received from `wget_wch()` into a Perl string. `SV` is the "scalar value" type.

See also: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html

Here with two `fprintf` inserted to see what is going on:

```
static void
c_wchar2sv(SV *    const sv,
           wchar_t const wc) {
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Set SV to a one-character (not -byte!) Perl string holding a given wide
  character
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (wc <= 0xff) {
        char s[] = { wc, 0 };
        fprintf(stderr,"Not UTF-8 string: %02x %02x\n", ((int)s[0])&0xFF, ((int)s[1])&0xFF);
        sv_setpv(sv, s);
        SvPOK_on(sv);
        SvUTF8_off(sv);
    } else {
        char s[UTF8_MAXBYTES + 1] = { 0 };
        char *s_end = (char *)UVCHR_TO_UTF8((U8 *)s, wc);
        *s_end = 0;
        fprintf(stderr,"UTF-8 string: %02x %02x %02x\n", ((int)s[0])&0xFF, ((int)s[1])&0xFF, ((int)s[2])&0xFF);
        sv_setpv(sv, s);
        SvPOK_on(sv);
        SvUTF8_on(sv);
    }
}
```

## Test code using perl-Curses

- Tried with perl-Curses-1.36-9.fc30.x86_64
- Tried with perl-Curses-1.36-11.fc31.x86_64

**If you try it, hit BACKSPACE to get out of the loop, because CTRL-C is no longer interpreted.**

A lot of code below, but the critical area is marked with `----- Testing`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# pmap -p PID
# shows the per process using 
# /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.1
# /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Curses/Curses.so

# Trying https://metacpan.org/release/Curses

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;          # Meaning "This lexical scope (i.e. file) contains utf8"

use Curses;        # On Fedora: dnf install perl-Curses

# This didn't fix it 
# https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html

use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

# https://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-setlocale-function

use POSIX ();
my $loc = POSIX::setlocale(&POSIX::LC_ALL, "");

# ---
# Surrounds the actual program
# ---

sub setup() {
   initscr();
   raw();
   keypad(1);
   noecho();
}

sub teardown {
   endwin();
}

# ---
# Mainly for prettyprinting
# ---

my $special_keys = setup_special_keys();

# ---
# Error printing
# ---

sub mt {
   return sprintf("%i: ",time());
}

sub ae {
   my ($x,$fname) = @_;
   if ($x == ERR) { 
      printw mt();
      printw "Got error code from '$fname': $x\n"
   }
}

# ---
# Where the action is
# ---

sub announce {
   my $res = printw "Type any character to see it in bold! (or backspace to exit)\n";
   ae($res, "printw");
   return { refresh => 1 }
}

sub read1ch {
   # Read a next character, waiting until it is there.
   # Use the wide-character aware functions unless you want to deal with
   # collating individual bytes yourself!
   # Readings:
   # https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses#Wide-Character-Aware-Functions
   # https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties
   # https://www.ahinea.com/en/tech/perl-unicode-struggle.html
   # https://hexdump.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/character-encoding-issues-part-ii-perl/
   my ($ch, $key) = getchar();
   if (defined $key) {
      # it's a function key
      printw "Function key pressed: $key"; 
      printw " with known alias '" . $$special_keys{$key} . "'" if (exists $$special_keys{$key});
      printw "\n";
      # done if backspace was hit
      return { done => ($key == KEY_BACKSPACE()) }
   }
   elsif (defined $ch) {
      # "$ch" should be a String of 1 character

      # ----- Testing

      printw "Locale: $loc\n";
      printw "Multibyte output test: öüäéèà периоду\n";
      printw sprintf("Received string '%s' of length %i with ordinal 0x%x\n", $ch, length($ch), ord($ch));

      {
         # https://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html
         use bytes;
         printw sprintf("... length is %i\n"     , length($ch));
         printw sprintf("... contents are %vd\n" , $ch);
      }

      # ----- Testing

      return { ch => $ch }
   }
   else {
      # it's an error
      printw "getchar() failed\n";
      return {}
   }
}

sub feedback {
   my ($ch) = @_;
   printw "The pressed key is: ";
   attron(A_BOLD);
   printw("%s\n","$ch"); # do not print $txt directly to make sure escape sequences are not interpreted!
   attroff(A_BOLD);
   return { refresh => 1 }  # should refresh
}

sub do_curses_run {

   setup;

   my $done = 0;
   while (!$done) {
      my $bubl;
      $bubl = announce(); 
      refresh() if $$bubl{refresh};
      $bubl = read1ch();
      $done = $$bubl{done};
      if (defined $$bubl{ch}) {
         $bubl = feedback($$bubl{ch}); 
         refresh() if $$bubl{refresh};
      }
   }

   teardown;
}

# ---
# main
# ---

do_curses_run();


sub setup_special_keys {
   # the key codes on the left must be called once to resolve to a numeric constant!
   my $res = {
      KEY_BREAK()       => "Break key",
      KEY_DOWN()        => "Arrow down",
      KEY_UP()          => "Arrow up",
      KEY_LEFT()        => "Arrow left",
      KEY_RIGHT()       => "Arrow right",
      KEY_HOME()        => "Home key",
      KEY_BACKSPACE()   => "Backspace",
      KEY_DL()          => "Delete line",
      KEY_IL()          => "Insert line",
      KEY_DC()          => "Delete character",
      KEY_IC()          => "Insert char or enter insert mode",
      KEY_EIC()         => "Exit insert char mode",
      KEY_CLEAR()       => "Clear screen",
      KEY_EOS()         => "Clear to end of screen",
      KEY_EOL()         => "Clear to end of line",
      KEY_SF()          => "Scroll 1 line forward",
      KEY_SR()          => "Scroll 1 line backward (reverse)",
      KEY_NPAGE()       => "Next page",
      KEY_PPAGE()       => "Previous page",
      KEY_STAB()        => "Set tab",
      KEY_CTAB()        => "Clear tab",
      KEY_CATAB()       => "Clear all tabs",
      KEY_ENTER()       => "Enter or send",
      KEY_SRESET()      => "Soft (partial) reset",
      KEY_RESET()       => "Reset or hard reset",
      KEY_PRINT()       => "Print or copy",
      KEY_LL()          => "Home down or bottom (lower left)",
      KEY_A1()          => "Upper left of keypad",
      KEY_A3()          => "Upper right of keypad",
      KEY_B2()          => "Center of keypad",
      KEY_C1()          => "Lower left of keypad",
      KEY_C3 ()         => "Lower right of keypad",
      KEY_BTAB()        => "Back tab key",
      KEY_BEG()         => "Beg(inning) key",
      KEY_CANCEL()      => "Cancel key",
      KEY_CLOSE()       => "Close key",
      KEY_COMMAND()     => "Cmd (command) key",
      KEY_COPY()        => "Copy key",
      KEY_CREATE()      => "Create key",
      KEY_END()         => "End key",
      KEY_EXIT()        => "Exit key",
      KEY_FIND()        => "Find key",
      KEY_HELP()        => "Help key",
      KEY_MARK()        => "Mark key",
      KEY_MESSAGE()     => "Message key",
      KEY_MOUSE()       => "Mouse event read",
      KEY_MOVE()        => "Move key",
      KEY_NEXT()        => "Next object key",
      KEY_OPEN()        => "Open key",
      KEY_OPTIONS()     => "Options key",
      KEY_PREVIOUS()    => "Previous object key",
      KEY_REDO()        => "Redo key",
      KEY_REFERENCE()   => "Ref(erence) key",
      KEY_REFRESH()     => "Refresh key",
      KEY_REPLACE()     => "Replace key",
      KEY_RESIZE()      => "Screen resized",
      KEY_RESTART()     => "Restart key",
      KEY_RESUME()      => "Resume key",
      KEY_SAVE()        => "Save key",
      KEY_SBEG()        => "Shifted beginning key",
      KEY_SCANCEL()     => "Shifted cancel key",
      KEY_SCOMMAND()    => "Shifted command key",
      KEY_SCOPY()       => "Shifted copy key",
      KEY_SCREATE()     => "Shifted create key",
      KEY_SDC()         => "Shifted delete char key",
      KEY_SDL()         => "Shifted delete line key",
      KEY_SELECT()      => "Select key",
      KEY_SEND()        => "Shifted end key",
      KEY_SEOL()        => "Shifted clear line key",
      KEY_SEXIT()       => "Shifted exit key",
      KEY_SFIND()       => "Shifted find key",
      KEY_SHELP()       => "Shifted help key",
      KEY_SHOME()       => "Shifted home key",
      KEY_SIC()         => "Shifted input key",
      KEY_SLEFT()       => "Shifted left arrow key",
      KEY_SMESSAGE()    => "Shifted message key",
      KEY_SMOVE()       => "Shifted move key",
      KEY_SNEXT()       => "Shifted next key",
      KEY_SOPTIONS()    => "Shifted options key",
      KEY_SPREVIOUS()   => "Shifted prev key",
      KEY_SPRINT()      => "Shifted print key",
      KEY_SREDO()       => "Shifted redo key",
      KEY_SREPLACE()    => "Shifted replace key",
      KEY_SRIGHT()      => "Shifted right arrow",
      KEY_SRSUME()      => "Shifted resume key",
      KEY_SSAVE()       => "Shifted save key",
      KEY_SSUSPEND()    => "Shifted suspend key",
      KEY_SUNDO()       => "Shifted undo key",
      KEY_SUSPEND()     => "Suspend key",
      KEY_UNDO()        => "Undo key"
   };

   for (my $f = 1; $f <= 64; $f++) {
      $$res{KEY_F($f)} = "KEY_F($f)"   
   }

   return $res

}
```

Comment: Without knowing much about the module, i don't see the uf8 encoding in streams enabled? Like `use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));` at the top of the code? Or is the module supposed to take care of this?

Comment: @zdim Thank you. I have perl-Curses-1.36-9.fc30.x86_64 ... the `getchar()` is specifically meant to deal with wide-character annoyances, I man not sure whether I should set the encoding of STDIN ... doesn't everything come via the tty device? I will try...

Comment: OK, it looks like I can't have that version easily (the cpanm install bombed badly -- perhaps system's curses on my CentOS7 are too old for it).  The encoding has to be set on streams, yes; the question is whether the library does it or not.  It's easy to try though: just add the line from my first comment at the top of the program. See [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)

Comment: @zdim Thanks. That didn't work though ... no change. I will add this to the question.

Comment: The difference between `binmode` and `open` pragma I'd say is that `open` is a cleaner way than mucking about with `binmode`, and it takes care of all standard streams  (the pragma is also lexical); the `binmode` lines shown in the code aren't taking care of `STDIN`.  Then, if there are yet other channels of input (say `@ARGV`, sockets...) you'd need `Encode::decode` or an equivalent.

Comment: @zdim - Okay, switching this in the code.

Comment: But by the looks of things`getchar` should deal with it; then you don't want to also do it yourself.

Comment: [(I got to install the lib for v5.30 under perlbrew -- was just missing the system -devel package, duh).  So ... that `getchar()` works just fine; try to simply `say $ch;` right after it and it prints correctly (if you do `use open...` or `binmode`, othrewise it prints the right character and warns).  looking into it...

Comment: yeah, printing "normally" (`say` or `print`) all around that `printw` puts out the correct (multibyte) character.  However, when I replace `printw` (with `printf`) I don't get the bold for any characters.  Can't dig into it more right now...

Comment: I can replace `printw` with `addstr()`+`printf` and get that print (of mutlibyte utf8 char) to work, but then bold still doesn't. That of course wouldn't be a solution, but may be usefule debugging... (Btw, detailed documentation follows from `man 3 ncurses` -- further down the page there is a list of man pages for each function, like `man curs_printw` etc)

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu 19.10, perl version 5.30) by interpreting the encoding from `getchar()` as `iso-8859-1`. So after `($ch, $key) = getchar()` do a `$ch = Encode::decode("iso-8859-1", $ch )`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you. That's certainly a workaround but I wanted to break into full UTF-8. I will try whether it works in pure C next.

Comment: `decode("iso-8859-1", $x")` makes no sense. It's a no-op. (It may create a string with a different internal format, but nothing should care about that. This would be indicative of a bug *elsewhere*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it looks correct.

Running your script with *strace* can help...  I did this to see the system calls:

```
strace -fo strace.out -s 1024 ./foo
```

and could see the reads, messages, etc.  Getting a similar trace for ncurses could be done using a debug-library, though packagers haven't been consistent about providing one with tracing enabled.

**`ü`** in UTF-8 is **`\303\274`** (octal), and its Unicode value is **`252`** (decimal), or **`0xfc`** (hexadecimal).  This part of the question seems to have missed that point:

> That's just a fat NOPE, when pressing ü one sees:
>
> `Obtained win_t 0x00fc`
>
> So the correct code is run, but the data is ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. So it's wget_wch which behaves badly. So it's a curses config problem. Huh.

[`wget_wch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html) returns (for practical purposes) a Unicode value (not a sequence of UTF-8 bytes).  The ISO-8859-1 codes 160-255 happen to (not coincidentally) match the Unicode code-points, though the latter would certainly be *encoded* differently in UTF-8.

[`wgetch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) would return the UTF-8 bytes, but the Perl script would only use that as a fallback (since that would lead to having the Perl script convert UTF-8 strings to Unicode values).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have to think about this.

Comment: Ok, I have added an "answer". Apparently Perl has a problem with `sprintf` and the Curses lib has a problem with `printw`. But the data is indeed correctly received. Just not correctly printed.

Answer (score 5):

[ *This answer assumes libncursesw is available and being used. Trying to output "wide characters" without wide character support makes no sense :)* ]

---

**Short Answer**

`getchar` works fine. It returns a string of Unicode Code Points (aka decoded text), which is ideal.

`printw` is broken, but it can be made to accept a string of Unicode Code Points (aka decoded text) by adding the following to the program:

```perl
{
   # Add wide character support to printw.
   # This only modifies the current package (main),
   # so it won't affect any code by ours.
   no warnings qw( redefine );
   sub printw { addstring(sprintf shift, @_) }
}
```

---

**Is There a Problem with `getchar`?**

So you believe there's a problem with `getchar`. Let's try to confirm that by checking what `getchar` returns. We'll do that by adding the following:

```perl
printw("String received from getchar: %vX\n", $ch);
```

(`%vX` will print the value each character of the string in hex, joined by periods.)

- When pressing `e` (U+0065), a 7-bit char, one sees:

  ```
  String received from getchar: 65
  ```
- When pressing `é` (U+00E9), an 8-bit char, one sees:

  ```
  String received from getchar: E9
  ```
- When pressing `ē` (U+0113), a 9-bit char, one sees:

  ```
  String received from getchar: 113
  ```

In all three cases, we get a string that's exactly one character long, and that character consists of the Unicode Code Point of the input.<sup>[1]</sup> This is exactly what we want. Applying and removing character encodings should be done at the periphery so that the main logic of the program doesn't have to worry about encodings, and this is being done.

Conclusion: There is no problem with `getchar`.

---

**Is There a Problem with `printw`?**

So the problem must be with the output. To confirm this, I added the following to your program:

```perl
sub _d { utf8::downgrade( my $s = shift ); $s }
sub _u { utf8::upgrade(   my $s = shift ); $s }

for (
   [ "7-bit, UTF8=0" => _d(chr(0x65)) ],   # Expect e
   [ "7-bit, UTF8=1" => _u(chr(0x65)) ],   # Expect e
   [ "8-bit, UTF8=0" => _d(chr(0xE9)) ],   # Expect é
   [ "8-bit, UTF8=1" => _u(chr(0xE9)) ],   # Expect é
   [ "9-bit, UTF8=1" => chr(0x113)    ],   # Expect ē
) {
   my ($name, $chr) = @$_;
   printw("%s: %s\n", $name, $chr);
}
```

Output:

```
7-bit, UTF8=0: e
7-bit, UTF8=1: e
8-bit, UTF8=0:
8-bit, UTF8=1: é
9-bit, UTF8=1:  S
```

From the above, we observe:

- We see a difference between the results for `_d(chr(0xE9))` and `_u(chr(0xE9))` even though both scalars contain the same string (`_d(chr(0xE9)) eq _u(chr(0xE9))` is true). This function therefore suffers from The Unicode Bug.
- Based on the 8-bit tests, it appears to accept Unicode Code Points (decoded text) rather than UTF-8. This is ideal.
- Based on the 9-bit test, it doesn't appear to accept Unicode Code Points. Subsequent testing shows it doesn't accept the UTF-8 encoding of `chr(0x113)` either.

Conclusion: There are major problems with `printw`.

---

**Fixing the Problem with `printw`**

Working around The Unicode Bug is easy, but the lack of support for characters above 0xFF is a show-stopper. Let's dig into the code.

Ok, we don't have to look far for the problem. We see that `printw` is defined in terms of `addstr`, and `addstr` predates wide character support.  `addstring` is the counterpart with wide character support, so let's make `printw` use `addstring` instead of `addstr`.

```perl
{
   # Add wide character support to printw.
   # This only modifies the current package (main),
   # so it won't affect any code by ours.
   no warnings qw( redefine );
   sub printw { addstring(sprintf shift, @_) }
}
```

Output:

```
7-bit, UTF8=0: e
7-bit, UTF8=1: e
8-bit, UTF8=0: é
8-bit, UTF8=1: é
9-bit, UTF8=1: ē
```

Bingo!

From the above, we observe:

- We see no differences between the results for the `UTF8=0` tests and their corresponding `UTF8=1` tests. Therefore, this function doesn't suffer from The Unicode Bug.
- It accepts strings of Unicode Code Points (decoded text) throughout. Notably, it's not expecting UTF-8 or the locale's encoding.

This is exactly what we expect/desire.

---

1. Specifically, `getchar` isn't returning the iso-8859-1 encoding of the input as you believed. The confusion is understandable because Unicode is an extension of iso-8859-1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210963/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-perl-curses-expecting-a-utf-8-encoded-multiby).

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Dickey correctly noted that *the right data is received*.

This took me some time to actually ascertain.

The confusion s down to the fact that that Perl's `sprintf` can't handle UTF-8 and Perl Curses `printw` can't handle the region `0x80` to `0x7F`.

This took even longer to ascertain.

In fact, I have opened a new question about this:

[Are there one (or two) solid bugs in the `curses` shim for Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971499/are-there-one-or-two-solid-bugs-in-the-curses-shim-for-perl)

Comment: waddwstr would be appropriate if Perl passed in an array of `wchar_t`'s (which is unlikely).  `waddstr` handles a UTF-8 string.  Perl "knows" when a string is UTF-8, and if it forgets (if the string is assigned to a *raw string*), its guess may result in the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Re "*The bytes of $ch are interpreted as ISO-8859-1.*", `sprintf`'s `%s` performs no interpretation whatsoever. It simply copies the characters from the parameter string one-for-one into the output string. For example, `sprintf("[%s]", $x)`, `"[$x]"` and `"[" . $x . "]"` are all equivalent

Comment: Re "*I'm not sure about the sprintf hack.*", It's not a hack; it just means that `printw` takes a format pattern like `printf` does. As you would with `printf`, you must either escape any `%` you want to print verbatim or use `printw("%s", "...")`.

Comment: @Ok for the "sprintf hack". This is indeed what the C interface expects: ` int printw(const char *fmt, ...);`Got it!

Comment: @ikegami I have moved this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971499/are-there-one-or-two-solid-bugs-in-the-curses-shim-for-perl